# How can I view my old notifications on Marshmallow?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notifications

I have come across several articles that say you can put a notification widget on your home screen by adding the settings widget, however, my phone running Marshmallow doesn't have either a Settings widget or a Notifications widget. Is there any way I can view my dismissed notifications without installing a third-party app?

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: @beeshyams No, it's not.

Comment: [Toaster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mars3142.android.toaster) app records all notifications made by **apps**. That may help to that extent

Comment: It doesn't cover dismissed **system** notifications

Comment: Let me know if that is what you are looking for, to post as an answer